# How to add an icon to files with certain extensions with a VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Right now, I am creating a VS Code extension for a language that doesn't exist yet. I don't want to create a whole file icon theme because this isn't my goal. How can I set an icon to a file with a certain extension?

I have already started creating an extension. It is a really simple one, just syntax highlighting. But I also want to add icons to certain files (with extension .abc, for example) because Visual Studio Code doesn't yet have an icon for this file format in it's icon theme.

Comment: Could you please clarify this question? It's not obvious what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Carl I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

As of v1.64, to set icons for languages from your extension you can use this in your `package.json`:

```
 "contributes": {  
     "languages": [
       {
         "id": "latex",
         // ...
         "icon": {
           "light": "./icons/latex-light.png",
           "dark": "./icons/latex-dark.png"
         }
       }
   ]
```

- more at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#language-default-icons